# regrouping with KStream semantics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Using kafka-streams, I want to group a stream `S` of elements `E` by some key `K1` while aggregating all values for that same key into a joined result `AGG`. This results in a KTable `T1`.

Depending on the aggregated result, the value should be repartitioned into another KTable `T2`, grouped by a key `K2` taken from the aggregated result `AGG`. So the aggregated result should generate the key for the next regroup.

In the end I'm only interested in a KTable `T2` where the key is `K2` and the value is `AGG`

However, this does not work. I only get a KTable `T` for the last value. Not a value for each key `K2`

I know the results of aggregation are only forwarded after some time, so I already tried to lower `commit.interval.ms` to 1 but to no avail.

I also tried to use `through` and write the intermediate results to a stream but that didn`t succeed as well.

```
val finalTable = streamBuilder.kstream("streamS")
                    .groupBy{ k, v -> createKey1(k, v) }
                    .aggregate(
                            { Agg.empty() },
                            { k, v, previousAgg ->
                                Agg.merge(previousAgg, v)
                            })
                    .toStream()
//                    .through("table1")
                    .groupBy { k1, agg -> agg.createKey2()}
                    .reduce{ _, agg -> agg }
```

For a stream `S` containing the following values:
`key1="123", id="1", startNewGroup="false"`
`key1="234", id="2", startNewGroup="false"`
`key1="123", id="3", startNewGroup="false"`
`key1="123", id="4", startNewGroup="true"`
`key1="234", id="5", startNewGroup="false"`
`key1="123", id="6", startNewGroup="false"`
`key1="123", id="7", startNewGroup="false"`
`key1="123", id="8", startNewGroup="true"`

I would like the end result to be a KTable having the following latest key-values:
`key: 123-1, value: 'key1="123", key2="123-1", ids="1,3"'`
`key: 234-2, value: 'key1="234", key2="234-2", ids="2,5"'`
`key: 123-4, value: 'key1="123", key2="123-4", ids="4,6,7"'`
`key: 123-8, value: 'key1="123", key2="123-8", ids="8"'`

The original stream `S` of elements is first grouped by `key1` where the aggregated result contains the groupby key `key1` and adds an extra field `key2` containing a combination of `key1` with the `id` of the first occurrence.
Whenever the aggregation received a value with `startNewGroup` set to `true`, it returns an aggregation with the `key2` field set to the `key1` and the `id` of the new value, effectively creating a new subgroup.
In the second regroup, we simple group by the `key2` field.

However what we really observe is the following:
`key: 234-2, value: 'key1="234", key2="234-2", ids="2,5"'`
`key: 123-8, value: 'key1="123", key2="123-8", ids="8"'`

Comment: Did you try `stream().groupBy().aggregate().groupBy().aggregate()` -- using a custom `transform()` does not seem to be the simples solution. Note, that converting the first result into `stream()` changes the semantics from "update" to "facts"

Comment: Actually, I did and it worked too, but you need to make sure the materializer in the first aggregate is configured not to cache the results when you want the results to be immediately available downstream. I think otherwise, it will wait and buffer the results.

Comment: It depends on your requirements, but if that is what you need, you can disable caching for the first aggregation via `Materialized.as(null).withCachingDisabled()`. -- What I don't understand is, why you say "However, this does not work. I only get a KTable T for the last value. Not a value for each key K2" ? And why does reducing the commit interval not give you "quicker updates" downstream is also unclear to me.

Comment: Also, why does a custom transformer help (ie, the answer you accepted)? If you feed the result from the first aggregation into the transformer, you would have the same behavior that upstream caching does not forward each update to the transformer? You would need to disable caching upstream, again.

Comment: Btw: you can also disable caching globally by setting `cache.max.bytes.buffering` to zero in `StreamsConfig`.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case is better to use [Processor API](http://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html). Processor API can be easily combine with Kafka Streams DSL ([Processor API integration](http://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#applying-processors-and-transformers-processor-api-integration)).

You have to implement Custom [Transformer](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Transformer.html), that will aggregate your messages for particular key in state store. When `startNewGroup=true` message arrive *old* messages for the key will be forward to downstream and *new* aggregation will start

You Sample Transformer might look as follow:

```scala
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Transformer
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorContext
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.KeyValueStore

case class CustomTransformer(storeName: String) extends Transformer[String, Value, Agg] {

  private var stateStore: KeyValueStore[String, Agg] = null
  private var context: ProcessorContext = null

  override def init(context: ProcessorContext): Unit = {
    this.context = context
    stateStore = context.getStateStore(storeName).asInstanceOf[KeyValueStore[String, Agg]]
  }

  override def transform(key: String, value: Value): Agg = {
    val maybeAgg = Option(stateStore.get(key))

    if (value.startNewGroup) {
      maybeAgg.foreach(context.forward(key, _))
      stateStore.put(key, Agg(value))
    }
    else
      stateStore.put(key, maybeAgg.map(_.merge(value)).getOrElse(Agg(value)))
    null
  }

  override def close(): Unit = {}
}
```